# If $a(P)$ and $b(P)$ are no. of points on, and outside a convex polygon $P$, then $\sum x^{a(P)}(1-x)^{b(P)}=1 $ for all real $x$,

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

**Problem:** Let $S$ be a finite set of points on the plane such that no three of them are on a line. For each convex polygon $P$ whose vertices are on $S$, let $a(P)$ be the $b(P)$ be the number of vertices, and the number of points outside the polygon respectively. A line segment, point and the empty set are considered to be convex polygons with $2,1,0$ vertices respectively. Prove that for all $x \in\mathbb{R}$,
$$\sum_P x^{a(P)}(1-x)^{b(P)}=1 $$ 
Where the sum is taken over all convex polygons in $S$. [**Assumption:** $0^0 = 1$]

I could prove the statement in the case where all the points of $S$ lie on a convex boundary [eg., a circle or ellipse or something similar], because any choice of points gives me a convex polygon. In other cases, calculations were getting very complicated. Can this problem be solved using some other indirect method (like, a probabilistic approach or contradiction) ?

Comment: I believe this was an IMO shortlist problem in one of the last 15 years, so solutions shouldn't be hard to find online.

Comment: It's an IMO 2007 training problem, but I couldn't find any solutions online

Comment: The LHS is also the sum $$\sum_{k=0}^nN_n(k)x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$$ where $n$ denotes the size of $S$ and $N_n(k)$ the number of convex polygons with $k$ vertices. To complete the proof (but I have not checked this completely), one might want to keep in mind that, for every $x$, $$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}=1$$

Comment: https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2006SL.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwi9gbPjh9_OAhXFNxQKHVMWDrEQFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNHKYRnxLjhS7R2AJkzcNeDjQ2Xp1g&sig2=nlFEME42R-zCsDzSUSMZTg

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you so much